# I want to close a google chrome tab via linux terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, web, chromium

I'm writing a script that opens chromium tabs. I need a command that closes that tab.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

[https://www.linux.org/threads/xdotool-window.10606/#:~:text=The%20xdotool%20is%20a%20utility%20used%20from%20the,of%20many%20xdotool%20commands%20to%20create%20large%20tasks](https://www.linux.org/threads/xdotool-window.10606/#:%7E:text=The%20xdotool%20is%20a%20utility%20used%20from%20the,of%20many%20xdotool%20commands%20to%20create%20large%20tasks).

Remember that you must also have an "xprop" package that displays the information necessary for "xdotool"

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, a mere link to an off-site solution is not an acceptable answer here; at the very least, please summarize what’s behind the link, in case it stops working, or visitors are unable or unwilling to click through.

Answer (score 0):

Xdotool - Window

The xdotool is a utility used from the terminal or in a script to manually perform keyboard, mouse and window input (see the Xdotool – Keyboard and Xdotool – Mouse article). The commands can also be used to make a script of many xdotool commands to create large tasks. Later articles will cover the xdotool ability to control desktop manipulation.

The syntax for xdotool depends on the command being used. The first, but very powerful command, is 'search'. The syntax is as follows:

search [options] pattern

The search command helps to find specific windows on a system.

There are twelve options available for search which are:

```
--class class_name – name of the window's class
--classname classname_name – name of the window's classname
--name name – title of the window
--maxdepth N – recursive search for window, default is -1 meaning infinite (all child windows too) and 0 means top windows only, depth of 1 or more can get most windows
--onlyvisible – results show only windows which are visible which have the IsViewable state
--pid PID_NUM – process ID number of the window
--screen N – number of the monitor on which the window is open (0 is first monitor, but defaults to all available screens)
--desktop N – number of the desktop or workspace
--limit N – maximum number of results to display. Default is no limit (--limit 0)
--all – requires that all conditions for a match are met when multiple options are specified
--any – requires that any condition is true when specifying multiple options
--sync – halt all commands until previous commands produce results
```

NOTE: To find the class and classname, use the command 'xprop' in a Terminal. Once typed, the mouse cursor changes to allow the user to click on a window. Once selected, 'xprop' displays information about the selected window. The line labeled 'WM_CLASS(STRING)' displays two entries. The first entry is referred to as the Instance or Classname and the second is the Class name. The two may be identical except in case as with Gedit:

Comment: If you copy from a website, at least mark it as a reference, and rather edit your existing answer than posting a completely new answer